# Почему условие if не срабатывает?

Tags: php

Есть форма:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>">
                  <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите номер телефона">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Заказать">
                </form>
```

PHP код:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $tel = $_POST['tel'];
                echo $tel;
                $to = "admin@ukr.net";
                $subject = "Заказ обратного звонка с сайта";
                $message = $tel;
                mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: no-reply@alkonarkostop.com.ua\r\n");
                echo "TRUE";
              }
              else{
                echo "false";
              }
```

Почему условие if не срабатывает?

Comment: Что подразумевается под "не срабатывает"?

Comment: не срабатывает, потому что письмо не отправляется, или даже ваши echo не показываются?
Вы тестируете локально или на сервере? Что в логах вебсервера?

Comment: Не срабатывает именно POST - он пустой. На хостинге делаю, нет доступа к логам..

Comment: В консоли браузера видно ушедшие данные?

Answer (score 1):

Если письмо не отправляется, то скорее всего проблема с настройкой sendmail.

Comment: C sendmail все отлично, не срабатывает именно POST - он пустой.

Answer (score -1):

POST пустой потому, что  в глобальный массив не передается значение "submit". Туда передается значение из инпута "tel". А инпут с именем "submit" - это кнопка отправки формы. Нужно исправить PHP-код на

```
if (isset($_POST['tel'])).....
```

Comment: Вообще-то если у инпута есть и `name` и `value` то он передается, если конечно не задействована js-магия типа `form.serialze`